# SQL - Every Month except the current month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to configure a select, which retrieves all the data from the table, except the data from the current month.

```
select COUNT(INCIDENT_ID),
DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DATE,'%m-%Y') AS formatted_date
from incident_view
where (create_year = YEAR(CURDATE()) or create_year = YEAR(CURDATE())-1) 
AND CREATE_DATE NOT (create_month = MONTH(NOW())
AND CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME = "Company"

GROUP BY formatted_date

ORDER BY 
YEAR(CREATE_DATE), MONTH(CREATE_DATE)
```

Would appreciate any help.

Cheers

Comment: why and/not, when `month(create_date) <> month(cur_date())` would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function to format and compare month(and year). The updated query look like the one below (haven't tested it yet though):

```
SELECT COUNT(INCIDENT_ID),
DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DATE,'%m-%Y') AS formatted_date
from incident_view
where (create_year = YEAR(CURDATE()) or create_year = YEAR(CURDATE())-1) 
AND DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DATE ,'%Y%m') <> DATE_FORMAT(now() ,'%Y%m')
AND CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME = "Company"

GROUP BY formatted_date

ORDER BY 
YEAR(CREATE_DATE), MONTH(CREATE_DATE)
```

Comment: What does "<>" mean?

Comment: <> us MySql syntax for 'not equal to'. If it is working fine then, I would appreciate if you accept the answer as correct.